# App Crashes When TextField is Empty

Tags: button, android-studio, crash, textfield

I have tried too many things but after pressing calculate(hesapla) button app crashes everytime.

For example:

```
if (vize1.getText().toString().equals("") || fina1.getText().toString().equals("") || sort1.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    islem_yazi.setText("FILL THE FIELDS");
                } // IT DOESN'T WORK
```

What should I write/do?

```
    import android.app.ActionBar;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.text.TextUtils;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.Window;
    import android.view.WindowManager;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;

    import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
AdView adView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    reklamiYukle();
    {

    }

    final Button hsp_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.hesapla);
    Button temizle = (Button) findViewById(R.id.temiz1);
    final EditText vize1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.vize);
    final EditText fina1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fina);
    final TextView islem_yazi = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.islem_yazi);
    final EditText sort1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sort);

    hsp_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {
            int v1 = Integer.parseInt(vize1.getText().toString());
            int f1 = Integer.parseInt(fina1.getText().toString());
            int s1 = Integer.parseInt(sort1.getText().toString());

            int m;
            float n, b, l, k, j, h;
            float bort;
            bort = (0.4f * v1) + (0.6f * f1);
            m = 1;
            n = 1.1f;
            b = 1.18f;
            l = 1.24f;
            k = 1.3f;
            j = 1.35f;
            h = 1.4f;

            if (vize1.getText().toString().equals("") || fina1.getText().toString().equals("") || sort1.getText().toString().equals("")){
                islem_yazi.setText("FILL THE FIELDS"); 
            }// IT DOES NOT WORK. APP CRASHES.

            else if (s1 > 100 || s1 < 0) {
                islem_yazi.setText("Sınıf Ortalaması 0 ile 100 Arası Olmalı");
            }
             else if (v1 > 100 || v1 < -2) {
                islem_yazi.setText("Vize Notunuz -2 ile 100 Arası Olmalı");
            }
             else if (f1 > 100) {
                islem_yazi.setText("Final/Büt Notunuz En Fazla 100 Olmalı");
            }
             else if (f1 < 0) {
                islem_yazi.setText("Final/Büt Sınavına Girmemişsiniz");
            }
             else if (s1 >= 60 && m * bort <= 38) {
                islem_yazi.setText(" Bağıl Ortalamanız = " + (m * bort) + "\nHarf Notunuz: FF ");


            } else if (s1 >= 60 && m * bort <= 45) {
                islem_yazi.setText(" Bağıl Ortalamanız = " + (m * bort) + "\nHarf Notunuz: FD");

            } else if (s1 >= 60 && m * bort <= 52) {
                islem_yazi.setText(" Bağıl Ortalamanız = " + (m * bort) + "\nHarf Notunuz: DD");


            } else if (s1 >= 60 && m * bort <= 59) {
                islem_yazi.setText(" Bağıl Ortalamanız = " + (m * bort) + "\nHarf Notunuz: DC");


            } else if (s1 >= 60 && m * bort <= 66) {
                islem_yazi.setText(" Bağıl Ortalamanız = " + (m * bort) + "\nHarf Notunuz: CC");


            } else if (s1 >= 60 && m * bort <= 73) {
                islem_yazi.setText(" Bağıl Ortalamanız = " + (m * bort) + "\nHarf Notunuz: CB");


            } else if (s1 >= 60 && m * bort <= 80) {
                islem_yazi.setText(" Bağıl Ortalamanız = " + (m * bort) + "\nHarf Notunuz: BB");


            } else if (s1 >= 60 && m * bort <= 87) {
                islem_yazi.setText(" Bağıl Ortalamanız = " + (m * bort) + "\nHarf Notunuz: BA");


            } else if (s1 >= 60 && m * bort <= 140) {
                islem_yazi.setText(" Bağıl Ortalamanız = " + (m * bort) + "\nHarf Notunuz: AA");

            }
        }
    });

    temizle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v.getId() == R.id.temiz1);
            vize1.setText("");
            fina1.setText ("");
            sort1.setText("");
        }
    });

    }

private void reklamiYukle() {
    adView=new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.reklam));
    LinearLayout layout= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.reklam1);
    layout.addView(adView);

    AdRequest adRequest=new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice (AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);

}

}
```

There is a Log Cat;

> com.ertugrulguleryuzgmail.sdunothesaplama E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                         java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
>                                                                                                at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
>                                                                                                at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:359)
>                                                                                                at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
>                                                                                                at
>   com.ertugrulguleryuzgmail.sdunothesaplama.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:74)
>                                                                                                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
>                                                                                                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
>                                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
>                                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>                                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
>                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>                                                                                                at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
>                                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>                                                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Print and post a stack trace.  Can't tell why based on what you've posted.  You can't either.  I'll guess and say you'll find a null pointer exception b/c a variable isn't initialized properly.

Comment: Show us the stacktrace...will help us a lot, to help you. Also do every one a favor and don't name objects and classes in other than english, in 99% cases its not an issue.

Comment: I am a newbie on this and don't know what is stack trace. But I can show log cat;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's because you want to convert empty string to int.
 here:

---

```
 int v1 = Integer.parseInt(vize1.getText().toString());
        int f1 = Integer.parseInt(fina1.getText().toString());
        int s1 = Integer.parseInt(sort1.getText().toString());
```

### Do this instead for all like:

```
 int v1 = "".equals(vize1.getText().toString()) ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(vize1.getText().toString());
```

Comment: WORKS LIKE A CHARM! Thanks a lot.

Comment: NP, do not forget to apply my other comments too (always put actual string bit in front when you using equals method like  "plain string".Equals (...);

Answer (score 0):

```
vize1.getText().toString().equals("")
```

---

change it to `"".equals(vize1.getText().toString())`

*(apply this to rest of your conditions in if statement)*

---

in your way if vize1 is null for any reason (maybe has not been declared yet) compiler will throw a nullPointException and crash the app.

Comment: Didn't work. But I have added Log Cat if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `isEmpty()` method to test the condition. It uses less code and is more clear about your intentions.